# Duda respecto a herencia java

Tags: java

Para acceder a los atributos privados de la clase padre las hijas pueden utilizar los métodos públicos de la clase padre y hacer operaciones necesarias o solo es poniendo proteccted los atributos del padre?

Comment: La prueba más sencilla es que te hagas una clase con atributos y métodos públicos, privados y protegidos, y hagas otra segunda que herede de la primera. Desde la segunda intenta acceder a los métodos y atributos de la primera, verás que solo podrás acceder a los métodos y atributos públicos y protegidos y no podrás acceder a los privados.

Answer (score -2):

Los hijos pueden acceder a los atributos y métodos públicos de la clase padre independientemente del ámbito de la relación y si la relación es pública los hijos pueden acceder a los atributos protegidos de la clase padre.